# Search for an iframe on a web Page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How to find an iframe is present on the web page or not?

The Html tag is given below

```
<div class="bluebox">
   <div class="title"><span>Preview</span></div>
   <div class="content">
      <iframe frameborder="0" src="about:blank" style="width:100%;height:488px;border:0 none;" id="previewFrame"></iframe>
   </div>
   <div class="box_shadow">
      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="right"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In my code I have written like :

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("previewFrame")));
System.out.println("Successfully switched to frame.");

boolean checkStatus = driver.findElement(By.id("previewFrame")).isDisplayed();
```

Error: Not able to find the iframe

Comment: Narayan Are you expecting any different answers?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
boolean isExists = true;
try {
       driver.findElement(By.id("previewFrame");
       // No exception means frame is present
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
       // Exception, no such frame is present
       isExists = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you switch to the `iframe`, Selenium's point of reference is everything contained in the `iframe`.

To check if Selenium has the correct reference, test for an element inside of the `iframe`.

As a side note, you can simplify your switchTo:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("previewFrame");
```

Answer (score 0):

try switching to the default page and then performing switching to the required frame.

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("previewFrame")));
```

Let me know if this helps you. Thanks.